# Using D3.select returning an empty array when selecting an SVG within React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I've been attempting to select to create a dynamic image map that shows/hides different elements of an SVG depending on certain selected parameters.

I've been trying to use D3 for this however I have tried multiple different ways of using the D3.select to work off of but all of them seem to only return empty arrays.

The code for importing, displaying and trying to select the SVG is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import $ from 'jquery';
import diagram  from '../svg/diagram.svg';

export default function D3SelectTest() {

  var svgNode = d3.select('#diagram-object');
  console.log("Select Test:", svgNode);
  svgNode.selectAll('g').each(function(){
    var elemID = $(this).find('title').text();
    console.log("Element Searched:", elemID);
  })

  return (
    <div class="div1" id="div1">
      <object type="image/svg+xml" data={diagram} id="diagram-object" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have also tried displaying the SVG from directly within react as an inline SVG and I only had the same results:

```
class D3SelectTest2 extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    var svgNode = d3.select('#diagram')

    console.log("Test Log");
    console.log("Select Test:", svgNode);
    svgNode.selectAll('g').each(function(){
      var elemID = $(this).find('title').text();
      console.log("Element Searched:", elemID);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg 
        id="diagram"
        ...>
      </svg>
    );
  }
}

export default D3SelectTest2 ;
```

In all of the test's I've done I haven't been able to get any logs returned from the "Element Searched" log but the hope is to get it to return each of the element titles within the SVG so that I know it's working properly.

Comment: I am not familiar with d3.js , but I think using arrow functions for eg:- using svgNode.selectAll('g').each(()=>{
    var elemID = $(this).find('title').text();
    console.log("Element Searched:", elemID);
  }) instead of     svgNode.selectAll('g').each(function(){
    var elemID = $(this).find('title').text();
    console.log("Element Searched:", elemID);
  })  may help. I think 'this' is not accessible inside the ...each(function(){}. Another solution would be to assign this to a global variable like let that=this; before the statement and using it .

Comment: I'mp pretty sure you do want `function()` syntax; it'll bind `this` to the selected element (a `<g>`). An arrow function would leave `this` bound to whatever it is in `D3SelectTest` or `componentDidMount`. Kona, Can we see some of the SVG here?

Comment: @BallpointBen I can't share the SVG directly, but its what I feel is quite standard. Main <svg> open tag a <style> tag, the <title> then its just the <g> tags. Within the g tags each element has a 'title', 'desc', 'path' & 'text'. The SVG is exported from Visio so the id's of the g tags aren't editable so the title tag is what i need to use for finding specific elements.

Comment: Your select for the SVG node is wrong.  Should be (note the #): `var svgNode = d3.select('#diagram')`.  I think that's your only issue.

Comment: @Mark sorry, that was a typo. I have the # in the code I must have missed it when writing the question sorry.

Comment: @Kona, hmm...  The rest of your code snippet runs fine for me.  See [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/p6kppj6OrTF4CfNV?preview)

Comment: Ok so it seems like the code is working... Sorry about this, For some reason the console is not showing the logs for the recurring function. Thank you for all the help on this.